# How can I start programming for Elementary OS?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elementary-os

The Elementary OS is really powerful and beauty operation system, based on Ubuntu, and I want build programs for the OS.
How can I start it? Any books, courses, step-by-step instructions etc? What do you can give advice to me for starting? I know the OS use Vala programming language, but I can't find any books for the one.

upd: Now I know on middle level CSS, HTML and PHP.

Thx for any answer,
best

Comment: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala

Comment: https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started/#getting-started

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Vala` is some kind of modern language frontend for `C` programming, primarily for the GObject world (but not exclusively). That means for programing in the GNOME ecosystem.

Not sure what you want to do - develop command line applications or graphical ones. For graphical ones you will want to learn the `Gtk+` framework. It is based upon the `GLib` framework, which you would use if you want to create command line applications.

I would recommend start reading on the `Gtk+` documentation:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.22/

This is all in the `C` world because the framework itself in `C`. So when using `Vala` things will be a bit different (but not too much). It can be challenging doing both at the same time - but it should be a good read and excercise to get a basic understanding on how things work.

Comment: Can apps built using `python` or `C++` run on elementary os or it supports `vala` only??

Comment: The applications are just regular GTK applications. You can write them in any language GTK bindings are available for. So Python and C++ are fine too.

Comment: Thanks, well What about Python with QT framework (in case i didn't use GTK)??

Comment: It will run just fine. The look and feel may be different though. Depending how close Qt themes to Elementary.

Answer (score 0):

Start at the offical elementary website: https://elementary.io/docs/code/getting-started#getting-started

As stated by Florian Zwoch, the language of choice is Vala in combination with the GTK+ ("GUI-Framework").

Read https://chebizarro.gitbooks.io/the-vala-tutorial/content/ for a introduction to the Vala language itself.

Then go to [Valadoc](https://valadoc.org/) for a comprehesive documentation as well as some introduction turorials on the topic Vala in combination with GTK+ / Application development.

(Besides Vala, GTK+ has bindings for almost any language, with C/C++ and Python being the more popular)

Then you can look at the official Github repository and study the sources of the elementaryos apps: https://github.com/elementary

You find a few more helpful code examples on gnome.org: https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Vala/Examples